# Showing a continuous function is smooth

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

[image]

This is an exercise I need to solve but I am stuck at the "if" part of (b). I think I have to get some smooth charts, but since the elements of $C(N)$ and $C(M)$ are only real-valued functions, I can't  find a way to get charts. Could anyone help me?

Comment: The components of charts in $M$ and $N$ are elements of their $C^\infty$'s.

Comment: @orele's comment is almost perfect - you just need to extend the coordinate functions on the chart to all of the manifold using bump functions.